# I can't get the value I want

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N6XQ.png)

```
username = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"root\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/div[1]/span[2]"))).get_attribute("span"))
print(username)
```

I can't print the value I want to get please help

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/div[1]/span[2]"}
```

this is my error

Comment: That image does not include the element with `id="root"`, so we can't tell if the xpath is correct or not.

Comment: And even if it were correct, I think you want `.text` on the end, not `.get_attribute("span")`.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

The locator you are looking for is the XPath

```
//span[text()='username']/following-sibling::span
^ Get a SPAN
      ^ that contains the text "username"
                         ^ that has a sibling SPAN
```

This is likely going to pick up all of these on the page, assuming the HTML is the same for all of them and it probably is which means you can loop through them.

You are using `.get_attribute("span")` but you need to use `.text()` to get the text contained in the SPAN element. I also removed the extra parentheses around the entire line.

```
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='username']/following-sibling::span"))).text
print(f'username: {username}')
```

If you wanted to print them all out,

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
for username in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='username']/following-sibling::span")):
    print(f'username: {username}')
```